# Validate a form only if every input is empty

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

Well, the question's pretty self-explanatory. I've been looking for a while and haven't found a proper way to do this kind of validation.

All I need to do is to run an error message if **all the inputs** are empty. If one of them is filled, then I don't need to stop the form from submitting.

I thought something like:

```
function checkForm() {
    $('input').each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == "" ){
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

But this will stop my form if there's, at least, one input without data.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse your logic since you want to check if the value is non-empty for one input field.

Also you probably want to return from your actual function and not from the callback which has no effect.

```js
function checkForm() {
    let bool = false;
    $('input').each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() !== '' ){
          bool = true;
        }
    });
    console.log(bool);
    return bool;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button onclick="checkForm()">check</button>
```

Comment: Both answers were correct, but the callback issue appointed here makes this one the best one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Reverse your logic. I.e. return `true` if any input has a value, otherwise return `false`:

```
function checkForm() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return false;
};
```